# Address of function prototypes

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

In new Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 forward declaration of functions gives "top-most" address to that function. They are not sequential anymore, if the one has prototype it will sit on top of memory space (as it is actually in source code - on top).

Code like this will not work as it suppose to:

```
int Offset = (VOID*)MAIN - (VOID*)FUNC1
```

How to prevent this, other then prototyping all functions? I hope there is some linker switch or Project settings.

Comment: `Code like this will not work as it suppose to` This code is not supposed to work in any particular way. I'm pretty sure it won't even compile. What are you really trying to achieve? Your question sounds like an instance of [the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Well it works so sue me :). It is obvious that I'm trying to see how big is my function + alingment presented by the compiler. It used to work just fine in older VS.

Comment: And why are you trying to see how big your function is? What is the ultimate goal of the exercise?

Comment: Ahh that Igor, well reinventing the wheel with code injection and address independent code. We should focus on the fact in works in <VS2010 but not anymore :)

Comment: It was never guaranteed to work. To the extent it appeared to, it only did by accident. I'm not sure what it is you want to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

Visual Studio 2012/2013 flag **Project -> General ->
Whole Program Optimization : No Whole Program Optimization** is used (in)correctly. With **Use Link Time Code Generation** TOP-DOWN compiling is archived regardless of how many forward declarations are there.

Someone more experianced should solve the mystery.